# Why does my async validator not appear to work?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I create simple reactive form and i want to use async validator. To do it I use third argument of formBuilder.

Here is the code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group(
      {
        login: [
          '',
          [Validators.required, this.customValidator],
          [this.asyncValidator()],
        ]
      }],
      }
    );
  }
```

My async validator function looks like this:

```
  asyncValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    console.log('async');
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      console.log('control', control);
      return this.usersService.getUsers().pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('tap')),
        map((users) => {
          console.log(typeof users, users);
          return { usersExists: true }; // i want to launch error
          // return users ? { usersExists: true } : null;
        })
      );
    };
  }
```

However my async validator does not work because in the template I see error object without `userExists` key.

```
<pre>{{ form.controls.login.errors | json }}</pre>
```

Please help my repair my async validator. Now I deliberately throw error via:

```
return { usersExists: true };
```

Here is a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/at-ng-14-router-meglca?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

To be valid, an AsyncValidator should complete.

```
  asyncValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    console.log('async');
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      console.log('control', control);
      return this.usersService.getUsers().pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('tap')),
        map((users) => {
          console.log(typeof users, users);
          return { usersExists: true }; 
        }),
        take(1) // Take ensures completion
      );
    };
  }
```